# how come sudo give root privileges for a user not in /etc/sudoers?

Tags: administration, sudo

I just wonder how sudo privileges are found with ubuntu, from a technical point of view. 
Users with sudo privileges are not present in /etc/sudoers, so this looks a little bit exotic.

Was the source code of 'sudo' modified to look to other configuration files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default all members of *admin* group can use sudo to get root privileges:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: OMG, I took the '%' char for a comment. Too much LaTeX probably...